# ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Estou tendo um problema com oracle, ele não está aceitando uma subquery em um left join, se eu mudar para inner join funciona, mas muda o resultado do meu select então não atende a solução. o problema acontece com o seguinte exemplo:

```
    CREATE TABLE A (ID INT, NOME VARCHAR2(50))
    CREATE TABLE B (ID INT, ID_A INT, NUMERO NUMBER(8))
```

Query:

```
    SELECT A.NOME
    FROM A LEFT JOIN B
    ON A.ID = B.ID_A AND B.NUMERO = (SELECT MAX(NUMERO) FROM B B2 WHERE B2.ID_A = A.ID)
```

Preciso reescrever de uma forma que o oracle aceite mantendo como left join.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT A.NOME
  FROM A 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT B2.ID_A,
                         B2.OUTRA_COLUNA
                    FROM B B2
                   WHERE B2.NUMERO = (SELECT MAX(B3.NUMERO)
                                        FROM B B3
                                       WHERE B3.ID = B2.ID
                                     )
                 ) B ON (A.ID = B.ID_A)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas não está funcionando porque a tabela A não tem o campo número.

Comment: Reinterpretei tua query e refiz minha resposta. Veja se isto te atende.

Comment: Esta retornando mais de uma linha, deveria retornar uma só. Porque a query original no sql server retorna uma só por causa do max.

Comment: Esta solução não é performática, visto que o filtro A.ID = B.ID_A só será aplicado após a execução da query interna)